# How to Hide Date Menu from Datepicker in yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, datetimepicker

Basically in datetimepicker widget date choose first then time, How i can hide date option from widget and filter according to time. I tried but not working also i want to hide remove button

```
  [         'attribute'=>'time',
            'label'=>'Time',
             'format'=>'raw',
            'value'=>function($data){
             return date('h:i:s',strtotime($data->time));
            },
            'filter'=> DateTimePicker::widget([
                                               'model' => $searchModel,
                                               'attribute' => 'time',
                                               'clientOptions' => [
                                                   'autoclose' => true,
                                                   'format' => 'HH:ii',
                                                   'showOn' => 'button',
                                               ],
                                           ]),
            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '10%', 'style' => 'text-align:center'],

        ],
```

Comment: Which date-time picker do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [nkovacs/yii2-datetimepicker](https://github.com/nkovacs/yii2-datetimepicker), here is what you can do to display only the time selector.

```
...

'filter'=> DateTimePicker::widget([
    'model' => $searchModel,
    'attribute' => 'time',
    'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_TIME,
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'HH:ii',
        'showOn' => 'button',
    ],
]),

...
```

Note `'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_TIME,`

Comment: After i added this it show me fatal error undefined constant and sorry i am not using  nkovacs, i'm using **2amigos**

Comment: Which datepicker widget do you use?

Comment: 2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget seems not supporting "Time Only" view. Perhaps you need to switch to some other option.